# corrupted double linked lists in material preview mode

Tags: error

I'm using Blender on Ubuntu 20.04 (fully updated) and unfortunately it is highly unstable. I crashed very often, especially when I'm in Material preview mode.
For example when I try to parent one object to another in Material preview mode, which seems to work, and then click anywhere else i shows an error line similar to "double linked list corrupted" (it differs sometimes).
From this point on Blender doesn't react anymore to any input although it doesn't seem to be crashed (Blender doesn't write any kind of log or shows further messages). I can only kill the process and restart it.

To reproduce the problem:

- duplicate the default cube
- shift select both cubes
- parent them via ctrl+p (object keep transform)
- click anywhere else

If I do these steps in Solid mode everything is fine. As soon as I do the same step in Material preview mode, the error occurs. But this is only one example, this happens in various other situations, preferably in Material preview.

It happens on Blender 2.82 - 2.92 and it happens with factory-startup enabled, like for example:

```
wm_event_do_handlers: Handling event
wmEvent  type:1 / LEFTMOUSE, val:2 / RELEASE,
         prev_type:1 / LEFTMOUSE, prev_val:2 / RELEASE,
         shift:0, ctrl:0, alt:0, oskey:0, keymodifier:0, is_repeat:0,
         mouse:(1463,741), ascii:'', utf8:'', pointer:0x55869e5738d8
malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted
```

Any ideas what might cause this problem or how to tackle it? As it doesn't really crash, as far as I can tell, it doesn't write any logs and the debug mode doesn't show anything usable.

> **Solution:** If anyone else ever stumbles about this problem, it seems to only occur in Blender versions from the Ubuntu PPA of Thomas
> Schiex. The vanilla version don't show this behavior.

Comment: You should report a bug on https://developer.blender.org/.

Comment: If you have found a solution, feel free to post an answer to your own question.